# Half primes in the set

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, pigeonhole-principle

Let S be 30 element subset of {1,2,....2015} such that every pair of elements in S are relatively prime. Prove that at least half of the elements in S are prime numbers

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but according to this program I just ran, there are $305$ primes under $2015$. However, you want something not to be prime, you need to multiply two primes, but there are only $14$ primes under the $\sqrt{2015}$, so that likely has something to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an outline of the proof:

- Show that there are $14$ primes under $\sqrt{2015}$.
- Let $R$ be a set of $14$ composite coprime numbers under $2015$.  It is well-known that any composite number has a prime factor under its square root, so in this case, each of these composite numbers has one of the prime factors under $\sqrt {2015}$. Now, using that knowledge, show that there is no composite number coprime to all of the numbers in $R$ because otherwise, there would have to be a fifteenth prime under $\sqrt{2015}$.
- Now, you have shown that no more than $14$ composite numbers under $2015$ can be coprime. Using that knowledge, prove that at least $16$ elements in $S$ are prime or $1$ and thus there are at least $1% primes in $S$, concluding the proof.

Comment: Thank you. I think this works

Comment: Actually, you can conclude that there are $16$ elements in $S$ which are prime _or_ $1$. Hence, there are at least $15$ primes there.

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks for the catch!